# After submit keep the select box value as recently selected?

Tags: html, jsp, cookies, form-submit, html-select

After submitting, redirecting to the same jsp page select box value should be previously selected one.

```
<form action="CitySelection" method="POST">
   <select name="cityname" id="myselect" onchange="this.form.submit()">
      <option value="england">england</option>
      <option value="france">france</option>
      <option value="spain">spain</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

How to do this ?

Comment: Could you please post a sample of your code that you used to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to place your selected value in a hidden field on submit and on reload send it back to the page and then read it to re-select the value previously selected

Answer (score 1):

You can store selected value in hidden field and fetch that in your servlet and set again in request and on page load you can again set that value as selected.